# Error reaching public extension directory in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, extension, error

Extension download error
The PQcrm public extensions directory at [https://civicrm.org/extdir/ver=5.52.3|cms=WordPress](https://civicrm.org/extdir/ver=5.52.3%7Ccms=WordPress) could not be Entityed - please check your webserver can make external HTTP requests